# Как убрать 301 редирект WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, seo, редирект

На страницах `site.ru/product-tags/medicina/page/1/` `site.ru/product-category/perchatki/page/1/` и подобных идет 301 редирект на `site.ru/product-tags/medicina` и `site.ru/product-category/perchatki`.

Как убрать это излишнее перенаправление?

Comment: Почему это "излишнее"? Зачем убирать?

Answer (score 0):

Не надо это трогать. Это базовая функциональность WordPress для работы пагинации. Скорее всего, усилий потратите много (придётся что-то делать с ядром), а эффект от этого - нулевой. На скорость загрузки страницы редирект не влияет, потому что происходит на ранней стадии загрузки ядра. На SEO 301 тоже не влияет.